# Click event not working with the checkbox tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, click

i have this code below:

```
        html.push('<tr class="reservas">');
        html.push('<td> <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" data-name="' + bla.name + '" data-email="' + bla.email /> </td>'); // atribui os dados a atributos para serem acessados posteriormente por jquery.
        html.push('<td>' + bla.name + '</td>');
        html.push('<td>' + bla.email + '</td>');
        html.push('</tr>');
        $('tbody').append(html.join(""));


$(function(){
    $('.save').on('click', function(){
   });
});
```

The click event does not work, if i change for the body tag will work, but i need with the checkbox class.

Every help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use EventDelegation:

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.checkbox', function(){
        alert('salvo');
   });
});
```

From Docs:

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a
>   parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a
>   selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the
>   future.